# Auto-generating SQLJ source code

Tags: oracle, plsql, auto-generate, sqlj

Has anyone out here tried auto-generating sqlj source code , from oracle pl/sql packages or procedures ?

Comment: Yes and it works. You might want to highlight the specifics you would want to know about if you expect this question to be answered in a more throughout way.

Comment: Thanks @mulander. I kind have managed it using ANTLR. Do you have an alternate way ? What I am trying to do is geenerate .java or .sqlj source code from oracle plsql packages/package bodies/procedures.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JPublisher](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31226/intro.htm) to automatically generate java classes for sqlj based on Oracle PL/SQL stored procedures. Below is the setup I typically use, you might want to experiment with *types flags (setting them either to oracle or jdbc).

```
sqlj/bin/jpub --user db_user -case=mixed -compile=false -omit_schema_names -sql=package_name -usertypes=oracle -numbertypes=jdbc -lobtypes=oracle -builtintypes-jdb -package=namespace -plsql-file=package_name_wrapper.sql,package_name_dropper.sql -plsqlpackage=package_name_jpubwrapper
```

Comment: Thanks @Mulander. Problem is that JPublisher only creates a SQLJ wrapper on existing plsql objects, compared to converting the plsql object into java.